# gprs modem AT vz. data mode

Tags: at-command, gprs

I'm using [Cinterion, PLS8-E](http://www.seapraha.cz/download/pls8-e_atc_v01000_tcm216-155309.pdf%20%22%22).

I have opened socket connection through gprs, sending, receiving data. And I have information screen filled with:

- Network & signal
- LAC/TAC
- CID
- 2G/3G/4G connection

All this information I'm getting from modem after powering up modem and before I bring up ppp0 interface and create socket connection through it.

what I need is to periodicly update information screen and every 30 sec ask modem:

- "AT+CSQ"
- "AT^SMONI"

How can I do this while opened socket connection throuh it?

Or if you can point me to any web page where I can learn about this, it would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I can bind /dev/ttyACM0 to pppd and AT commands sent to /dev/ttyACM1